# Why does (require 'use-package) fail from my init file, but succeed interactively?

Tags: elisp, init-file, package

With the following init file, emacs chokes on the first line:

```
bash-4.3$ pwd
/Users/sean/.emacs.d

bash-4.3$ cat init.el 
(require 'use-package)
(use-package package)

bash-4.3$ emacs --version | head -n 1
GNU Emacs 24.4.1
```

However, when I run emacs 'normally' (with this init file) and perform the `require` manually, it succeeds.  Why would this happen?  What can I do to fix it that won't have me changing load-paths every time I update `use-package`?

---

It is interesting to note that, by specifying the load manually, no errors are reported:

```
bash-4.3$ emacs --batch -L init.el
```

However, starting emacs interactively shows the issue.

Comment: Not clear. You are changing the recipe on the fly here, so it's hard to answer you. And now you mention that you are **updating** library `use-package`? So this is not the ordinary `use-package.el`? Where is it? For `require` to work, the library needs to be in your `load-path` - that's the problem, AFAICT.

Comment: @Drew I'm sorry if I was unclear; I have in the past been seemingly forced to update load-paths by hand when I update packages with `package.el`.  (Org goes from version `20140101` to `20140201`, for instance.)  I obviously do not want to be updating my initialization file every time one of these updates occurs.  This *is* the ordinary `use-package.el`, just thinking ahead to when it will be updated upstream :)

Comment: Agreed, this is a duplicate.  Unfortunately, I can't vote yet.

Answer (score 7):

It is `package.el` (with `package-initialize`) that adds the subdirectories of `.emacs.d/elpa` to your load path; these are not loaded automatically.  Since `use-package` is in this directory, emacs doesn't see it until it encounters `(package-initialize)`.

```
(package-initialize)
(require 'use-package)
```

It would appear that `(package-initialize)` is called sometime *after* the initialization file has been loaded.  More information on the initialization sequence can be found in the manual:

- [`(emacs) Starting Up`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Starting-Up.html)

---

@Drew pointed out [in a comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2647/why-does-require-use-package-fail-from-my-init-file-but-succeed-interactivel/2652?noredirect=1#comment3615_2652) that

> … now that there is `package-enable-at-startup`, with `t` as the default value, `package-initialize` does get called after loading your init file.

Answer (score 0):

Library `use-package.el` is not in your `load-path`.

The `-l` command-line option expects a file name, not a library name. You need to use option `-L`.

See:

- [(emacs) `Action Arguments`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Action-Arguments.html)
- [(elisp) `Library Search`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Library-Search.html)

Comment: True, but this doesn't really answer the question. Start emacs interactively, then.

Comment: How does it not answer the question? Did you try using `-L` and specifying the directory for `use-package.el`? Or did you try specifying the *absolute* file name for it with `-l`?

Comment: The question wasn't truly about `--batch` usage, it was about *interactive* usage.  It's absolutely true that `use-package.el` isn't in my `load-path` when it processes `require`, but why does my `load-path` change before and after emacs processes my `init` file?  Shouldn't it be calling `normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path` *before* it processes my initialization file, or is that done with `package-initialize`?

Comment: It is done with `package-initialize` (as you have since found out). Or by updating `load-path` in your init file or using command-line option `-L` or in other code you load. Emacs doesn't guess where some library you `require` might be located. That's what `load-path` is for.

Comment: Yes, I understand that :) I just misunderstood the initialization sequence.  I was lucky enough to come on to the emacs boat *after* `package.el` was distributed with it, so it's always had that essence of 'it just works'; I never stopped to think about *when* it was configured (i.e. which forms allow it) to work.  Even after four years, I'm still learning :)

Comment: All of this means that, somewhere *after* the init file has been loaded, `(package-initialize)` is called.  That's the piece of information that lets the whole situation make sense.

Comment: You say: *somewhere* ***after*** *the init file has been loaded, `(package-initialize)` is called.*  No, you can invoke `(package-initialize)` in your init file. That's what people usually do.

Comment: OK, yes, now that there is `package-enable-at-startup`, with `t` as the default value, `package-initialize` does get called after loading your init file. But you can also call it yourself, in the init file.

Comment: Sorry again for all the confusion :)